# Saving and Retrieving Boolean Value from Windows Registry

Tags: windows, delphi, registry, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm attempting to save/retrieve a Boolean value from the Windows Registry using Delphi Rio (Firemonkey).  No matter which state I save, true or false, the code always returns a true value.  Here is a sample project that illustrates my method:

```
uses
  System.IniFiles, System.Win.Registry;

const
  AppRegKey = 'Software\Mycroft\TestApp';

procedure TForm2.btnReadClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Reg: TCustomIniFile;
  checked: boolean;
begin
  Reg := TRegistryIniFile.Create('');
  checked := False;
  if Reg.SectionExists(AppRegKey + '\State\BoxChecked') then begin
    checked := Reg.ReadBool(AppRegKey,'Show', True);
  end;
  if checked then
    ShowMessage('Checked')
  else
    ShowMessage('Unchecked');
end;

procedure TForm2.btnSaveClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Reg: TCustomIniFile;

begin
  Reg := TRegistryIniFile.Create('');
  Reg.WriteBool(AppRegKey + '\State\BoxChecked', 'Show', chkBrandNew.IsChecked);
end;
```

It appears the value is being updated in the Registry, so I'm not sure why it always returns a True value.  Can someone please point me in the proper direction?

Comment: You're passing `AppRegKey` instead of `AppRegKey + '\State\BoxChecked'` to `ReadBool()`.

Comment: And you leak memory. If you create an object, you must also make sure to free it at the appropriate time.

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing the same key name to `Reg.ReadBool()` that you pass to `Reg.WriteBool()`.

You are also leaking the `TRegistryIniFile` objects.

Try this instead:

```pascal
uses
  System.IniFiles, System.Win.Registry;

const
  AppRegKey = 'Software\Mycroft\TestApp';
  AppRegKey_BoxChecked = AppRegKey + '\State\BoxChecked';

procedure TForm2.btnReadClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Reg: TCustomIniFile;
  checked: boolean;
begin
  Reg := TRegistryIniFile.Create('');
  try
    checked := False;
    if Reg.SectionExists(AppRegKey_BoxChecked) then
    begin
      checked := Reg.ReadBool(AppRegKey_BoxChecked, 'Show', True);
    end;
    if checked then
      ShowMessage('Checked')
    else
      ShowMessage('Unchecked');
  finally
    Reg.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.btnSaveClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Reg: TCustomIniFile;
begin
  Reg := TRegistryIniFile.Create('');
  try
    Reg.WriteBool(AppRegKey_BoxChecked, 'Show', chkBrandNew.IsChecked);
  finally
    Reg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

That said, `TRegistryIniFile` is meant for backwards compatibility with old code that used to save configs using `TIniFile` and then migrated to the Registry. New code should not be using `TRegistryIniFile` at all.

```pascal
uses
  System.Win.Registry;

const
  AppRegKey = 'Software\Mycroft\TestApp';
  AppRegKey_BoxChecked = AppRegKey + '\State\BoxChecked';

procedure TForm2.btnReadClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Reg: TRegistry;
  checked: boolean;
begin
  Reg := TRegistry.Create;
  //Reg := TRegistry.Create(KEY_QUERY_VALUE);
  try
    checked := False;
    if Reg.OpenKeyReadOnly(AppRegKey_BoxChecked) then
    // if Reg.OpenKey(AppRegKey_BoxChecked, False) then
    begin
      if Reg.ValueExists('Show') then
        checked := Reg.ReadBool('Show')
      else
        checked := True;
      Reg.CloseKey;
    end;
    if checked then
      ShowMessage('Checked')
    else
      ShowMessage('Unchecked');
  finally
    Reg.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.btnSaveClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Reg: TRegistry;
begin
  Reg := TRegistry.Create(KEY_SET_VALUE);
  try
    if Reg.OpenKey(AppRegKey_BoxChecked, True) then
    begin
      Reg.WriteBool('Show', chkBrandNew.IsChecked);
      Reg.CloseKey;
    end;
  finally
    Reg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Remy - I feel kind of dumb now that you point out my obvious coding error.  That said, I'm trying to write code that will be cross compatible with OSX/IOS and so I don't think the direct use of the Windows Registry will work in that case. I've a more complex unit I picked up on line that handles both options for me and internally uses the TRegistryIniFile for that purpose.  I'm still new to Firemonkey (and don't yet have a Mac or iPad to test on yet) so if the TRegistry component will work for both I'm all for it.